# Insert within function fails with "query has no destination for result data"

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

Here is the complete example code:

```
CREATE TABLE testtbl (
  id     integer NOT NULL, 
  intval integer,
  strval varchar(64)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE testtbl_id_seq 
  START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 
  NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE CACHE 1;
ALTER SEQUENCE testtbl_id_seq OWNED BY testtbl.id;
ALTER TABLE ONLY testtbl ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT
  nextval('testtbl_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY testtbl ADD CONSTRAINT testtbl_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE FUNCTION insert_testtbl (p_intval integer, p_strval varchar(64)) 
  RETURNS integer AS $$ 
  DECLARE
    v_new_id integer;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testtbl (intval, strval) VALUES (p_intval, p_strval) 
      RETURNING v_new_id;
    RETURN v_new_id;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT insert_testtbl(1, 'One');
```

When I run this (PostgreSQL version is 9.6.1), I get:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_testtbl(integer,character varying) line 5 at SQL statement
```

This doesn't make sense; I *AM* specifying a destination for the result!

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *I am specifying a destination for the result!*

No you are not.

`RETURNING v_new_id;` simply means:
"*return the current value of the variable `v_new_id` from this insert statement*"

(which is `null` as the variable was never assigned a value)

You are not *storing* the generated value anywhere.

You either need to use an `into` clause:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_testtbl (p_intval integer, p_strval varchar(64)) 
  RETURNS integer AS $$ 
  DECLARE
    v_new_id integer;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testtbl (intval, strval) VALUES (p_intval, p_strval) 
      RETURNING id 
      INTO v_new_id; --<<< HERE
    RETURN v_new_id;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or convert everything it simple SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_testtbl (p_intval integer, p_strval varchar(64)) 
  RETURNS integer AS 
$$ 
  INSERT INTO testtbl (intval, strval) VALUES (p_intval, p_strval) 
  RETURNING id;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you!!

Comment: @RodTurnham: if this solved your problem, please accept the answer, so that your question is marked as solved.